# i want to change role=presentation to role=application in tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, text-editor, tinymce-5

I want to change role=presentation to role=application in "tinymce editor", because when I open in mobile device gray box display instead of text editor with toolbar menu bar. but it works fine on laptop in desktop view and mobile view both.

if any solution please suggest me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Hello i suggest switching to CKEditor which has a whole lot more support for this sort of thing :)

https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/